# Lemmatization for Root Word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm just starting to learn/play with NLP, and have come across the following behavior:

Using nltk, I extract the part-of-speech for words, and then lemmatize as follows:

```
import nltk
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def get_wordnet_pos(word):
    """Map POS tag to first character lemmatize() accepts"""
    tag = nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1][0].upper()
    tag_dict = {"J": wordnet.ADJ,
                "N": wordnet.NOUN,
                "V": wordnet.VERB,
                "R": wordnet.ADV}

    return tag_dict.get(tag, wordnet.NOUN)


def pos_and_lemmatize(str):
    return [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, get_wordnet_pos(w)) for w in nltk.word_tokenize(str)]
```

Doing `pos_and_lemmatize` (or just `wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize`) on the following words: `variability, variables, variance, variation` just returns the same word, instead of something like `vary`. Any way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Does this only happen on words that end with `-y`? I.e., you cannot get `multiply` from `multiplication` but it does work on `translate` from `translation`? Does the nltk documentation indicate this ought to have worked?

Comment: @usr2564301 `multiply` and `multiplication` both yield the input word, as do translate and translation. However `studies` does convert to `study` as I would have expected.